# changing storyboard after UIAlert button pressed

Tags: ios, uiview, storyboard

I want to change to the main menu after clicking main menu at the game over UIAlert

trying this:

```
    -(void)gameOver
{
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]
                          initWithTitle:@"Time's up!"
                          message:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"You've scored: %i points!", scoreCounter]
                          delegate:self
                          cancelButtonTitle:nil
                          otherButtonTitles:@"Submit to Leaderboards",@"Play Again",@"Main Menu", nil];
    [alert show];
}
-(void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex {
    if (buttonIndex == 1) {
        [self toMain];
    }
    if (buttonIndex == 2) {
        [self toMain];
    }
    if (buttonIndex == 3)
    {
        [self toMain];
    }

}
-(void)toMain
{
    mainMenu *main = [[mainMenu alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
    [self presentViewController:main animated:YES completion:NULL];
}
```

does nothing at all...

EDIT

fixed the button index, now facing a black screen after [self toMain]

Comment: do you have added the `<UIAlertViewDelegate> Protocol` in your `*.h` file?

Comment: Having the protocol explicitly declared shouldn't affect anything, but it is a good idea.

Answer (score 1):

Button indices start at 0, so with your 3 buttons, there is no way for the `buttonIndex == 3` branch to ever be called.

Source: [Apple Docs on UIAlertView](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIAlertView_Class/UIAlertView/UIAlertView.html)

Comment: Isn't cancel button at index 0?

Comment: thx, now it actually does something, now i'm facing a black screen after the [self toMain], what can that be?

Comment: @powerj1984 His cancel button is nil

Comment: @MartinJ that is for a different SO question.